# failover cluster creation Error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, sql-server-2014

I am creating a fail over cluster, but doing so i get the error "An error occurred while creating the cluster.
An error occurred creating cluster 'testCluster'.

This operation returned because the timeout period expired
"
Moreover following is my setup:
Node 1: SQLA 
Node 2: SQLP

I have created two Server with server 2012 OS. SQLA machine is the domain and has 3 iSCSI Targets configured in it. SQLP and SQLA is the initiators (Client). Moreover I ran the validation and tried creating cluster on SQLA machine.

I have attached the screen shots of Validations and Cluster Creation failure. Kindly suggest if i am missing anything in doing this activity.

http://www.filedropper.com/error_13

Comment: "SQLA machine is the domain" - can you explain what you mean by that? Do you mean SQLA is a domain *controller*?

Comment: yes Exactly SQLA machine is a domain controller

Answer (score 0):

Running Domain Services on a cluster node was always a bad thing to do, but it was possible in certain configurations.

Unfortunately this has changed with Windows 2012, and Windows 2012-R2.

Running a domain controller on a node, or trying to add a node running domain services to a cluster will no longer work.

This is documented here: [KB 2795523](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2795523)

Your solution is to run Domain services on a separate host, not on a cluster node.

HTH.